# Proof of: (A\B)∩(C\D) = empty set? [SOLVED]

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I have a quick question regarding the Set Theory. The task states:

> Find out if, for any given set, is true: (A\B)∩(C\D)=∅

(it is a rough translation from my language so.. sorry for that but I hope it's OK in terms of mathematics in English)

The results say that the statement is true but I can't seem to find the proof. I've spent like the last couple of hours trying to get to the result in many different ways and to find it online but without any luck.

Therefore I would love to hear any suggestions. At the moment, it seems to me that it doesn't apply for any given set but that's just my opinion.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

So after several debates with my peers and a math teacher we came to the conclusion: I was meant to find just one solution to prove the statement (thus I didn't have to prove it for all possible sets), thus making it super easy actually. It was my misunderstanding of the task.

Anyway, thanks to all of you for your suggestions (and for the speed).

Finally, if there's any desperate Czech student facing the same problem, here's the original task (so that it can be easily found):

> Zjistěte, zda pro libovolné množiny A, B, C, D platí (A\B)∩(C\D)=∅.

(Last note: If there's any Czech, or a person learning Czech, reading this - I know the translation might be slightly off but my math language understanding transfered into English is quite... well, there are some gaps)

Comment: For any given sets ?

Comment: Try $A=C=\{1\}$, $B=D=\varnothing$, and see what you get.

Comment: The statement can clearly be false for an appropriate choice of $ A, B, C, D $. For instance, respectively the set of birds, the set of cats, the set of ducks and the set of insects.

Comment: Do you mean $(A\setminus B)\cap (B\setminus A)?$

Comment: That's what I was thinking. But the result just state "true" (or "applies".. however you translate it). No conditions under which it's true. That's what extremly confuses me and I wasn't sure enough to think the result from the paper might be wrong.

Comment: to mfl:
Unfortunately not. It really contains 4 sets.

Comment: Perhaps you are to find the conditions under which the proposition is true, for example, mrf's suggestion could use all four sets simply by equating: If B = C, A=D, then $A\setminus B\cap C\setminus D = A\setminus C \cap C \setminus A = \varnothing$, which is true;

Comment: I suppose that is the only explanation to this task (though the task itself doesn't say that anywhere) but I was intrinsically hoping that the authors of the book would be nice enough to publish the whole solution. But I guess that might be the answer. We shall see tomorrow :D

If anyone else has any other suggestion to this problem, please let me know. But for now I suppose we can agree that it doesn't apply for any given set and is, thus, restricted by a specfic condition. That was my original idea - just wanted to know if I was overlooking something.

Comment: For any given set(s) $A\setminus B \cap C\setminus D=\emptyset$ is obviously not always true.  For any given sets $A \setminus B \cap B \setminus A  \emptyset$ is true and easy to prove.  For *some* sets  $A\setminus B \cap C\setminus D=\emptyset$ *could* be true and one can find the minimum conditions that would make it true ($A \cap C \subset B \cup D)$  .  So it's unclear what the problem is supposed to be